# Finding the Rejection Region for a wilcoxon signed rank test

Tags: r

So I had to iterate a uniform distribution on a population of 10, and find the V values of each. This is the code I used

```
 V=wilcox[1]
 for(i in 1:10000){
 uniform=runif(10,0,1)
 wilcox=wilcox.test(uniform,mu=.5)
 V[i]=wilcox[1]}
V1=as.numeric(V)
hist(V1,breaks=55)
```

I then made a histogram with 55 breaks. Now I need to find the RR with a significance level of .05, any ideas how to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the quantile at alpha equals 0.05 (0.95), this means using `quantile()` with `probs=0.95` over the simulated values `V1`. Here the code:

```
#Loop
V=numeric()
for(i in 1:10000){
  uniform=runif(10,0,1)
  wilcox=wilcox.test(uniform,mu=.5)
  V[i]=wilcox[1]
  }
V1=as.numeric(V)
q <- quantile(V1,0.95)
#Plot
hist(V1,breaks=55)
abline(v=q,col="red")
```

Output:

[image]

For two sided test:

```
#Loop
V=numeric()
for(i in 1:10000){
  uniform=runif(10,0,1)
  wilcox=wilcox.test(uniform,mu=.5)
  V[i]=wilcox[1]
}
V1=as.numeric(V)
q1 <- quantile(V1,0.025)
q2 <- quantile(V1,0.975)
#Plot
hist(V1,breaks=55)
abline(v=q1,col="red")
abline(v=q2,col="red")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Aaa yes, but wouldnt it be a two-sided test if not specified? So I would to the same code but make two  lines. one with .975 as the prob, and the other as .025 as the prob?

Comment: @Nich Yes, just set different quantiles and add to the plot as lines. I hope that helped to reach your goal!

Comment: @Nich I have added an update, I hope that is useful for you. Let me know how that goes!